# Constructing another dual to reach primal optimal

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems

In Boyd's convex optimization book, he gives an example of weak duality where dual optimal is strictly less than primal optimal. He says that the intuition behind this is that we were able to hide the solution inside a dent in G (G is the gray area)
[duality gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crQo8.png)

In this case we clearly have $p* > g(\lambda)$ where $g(\lambda) = \inf_x (f_0(x) + \sum_{i}^{m} \lambda_i . f_i(x))$

What if, instead of taking $f_1(x)$ we build the symetric?

$$g(\lambda) = \inf_x (f_0(x) + \sum_{i}^{m} \lambda_i . (f_i(x) \mathbb{1}_{[-\infty, 0]} (x) + (f_i(-x) \mathbb{1}_{]0, +\infty]} (x) ) )$$

Geometrically that should give us something like this:
[duality gap with symetric f1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZp58.png). The green line is the new hyperplane $\lambda t + u = g(\lambda)$

Now my questions are:

- Could it be even useful or interesting?
- Would there be any problem with differentiability at $u=0$ ?
- Could you provide an example of $(t,u)=(f_0(x),f_1(x))$ that would give an asymmetric gray area like in the first image so I can play with it?

Comment: What is your justification for building $g(\lambda)$ in this second manner? That's just the dual function for a different optimization problem. It cannot be tied back to the first.

Comment: From my understanding it is sometimes useful to compute the optimal value of the dual, because it is computationally tractable or there is an analytical solution, the book gives "water filling" as example. My suggestion for $g(\lambda)$ is indeed the dual of another problem but with the same optimal value than the original one. I was wondering if there are some problems where building the dual of this modified problem can be useful to find the optimal value.

Comment: The only reason that dual has the same optimal value is because you drew it that way. There's no reason to expect that the first and second primal problems above will have the same optimal value in general. What is more, it's not clear how it extends to higher dimensions (e.g., $x$ not a scalar).

Comment: Ok I see one error in my reasoning, it should be $(f_i(x) \mathbb{1}_{[-\infty, 0]} (f_i(x)) ... $ which is probably much harder to exploit. Other than that, the modified problem should have the same optimal value because the minimal value for $f_0(x)$ doesn't change and when $f_i(x)>0$, x is infeasible so we don't have to worry about those x. Am I doing a mistake as well?